# Debugging keeps going to a timer1_tick event in a closed form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer

I'm using a Parent form to show my other forms as MdiChild forms like this:

```
 If ActiveMdiChild IsNot Form4 Then
            ActiveMdiChild.Close()
            Form4.MdiParent = Me
            Form4.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            Form4.AutoScroll = False
            Form4.Show()
 End If
```

One of my forms (TimerForm) has a timer, but when I put a break-point in another form (Form4) and follow the code and before the debugging is finished, it goes to the timer1_event in the closed TimerForm.

I tried this on TimerForm:

```
Private Sub TimerForm_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    Timer1.Stop()
    Timer1.Dispose()
End Sub
```

I also tried `ActiveMdiChild.Dispose()` with no luck.

How to stop the Timer from firing after the form is closed ?
Thank you.

Comment: You might start by using explicit form instances.  Forms are classes, so created instances of them `frm = New Form4()` for example.

Comment: Thank you, I used it to show both forms, but the timer event still firing.

Comment: Is this just a threading-debugger-timing issue?  Can you test once with logging instead of debugging just to see if the timer is still doing firing after close without the debugger attached?

Comment: it is very strange maybe you initialize the timer again somewhere in your code?

Comment: This c# but I'm sure you can understand the code a little bit and search a bit to implement it. Look at the last answer or you might have a cause of the first one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526598/why-does-the-last-mdi-child-form-that-was-closed-not-get-garbage-collected

Comment: @GMan80013 I didn't understand what you said.

Comment: @jonathana No, I'm only initializing it once.

Comment: @Chillzy I tried that last answer but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all.

I solved my problem by programmatically adding Timer1_Tick event:

```
Private Sub TimerForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load    
    AddHandler Timer1.Tick, AddressOf Timer1_Tick
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
```

And removing the event on FormClosing:

```
   Private Sub TimerForm_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Timer1.Stop()
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    Timer1.Dispose()
    RemoveHandler Timer1.Tick, AddressOf Timer1_Tick
End Sub
```

Comment: unless you added the timer programmatically, you shouldn't have to add the handler. it is added with the designer. But if you did add it programmatically then yes this is obvious you need to add the handler. You might have a bug somewhere else but if it works, that's what it matters

Comment: Yes, I'm adding it programmatically. Thank you.